# I'm shopping for a child trailer. Should I get one with suspension?

Tags: trailer

I'm shopping for a child trailer. Models with suspension get quite expensive, but it seems like that would be a great feature to reduce strain on the kiddo.

If you have a trailer with suspension, do you find that it actually provides some benefit?

I'm currently looking at the Burley Solo.

Comment: If the kids complain, use a couple of thin pillows or cushions for comfort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a trailer with suspension, but I don't believe it has provided much benefit while cycling.  Mine is multi-use (jogger, stroller, ski) and I have found it has provided some benefit while hiking.

On the cycling side of things, most of the time I am pulling the trailer with a rigid bike (no suspension).  I am riding with 5 weight bearing contact points while my kiddos are riding with a full body contact area and no need to maintain control (which is what suspension is designed for).  When they were younger, my trailer had an infant sling that kept them fully suspended (similar to a hammock).  Now that they are old enough and large enough, they sit in the trailer proper and receive what I perceive to be very little benefit from the suspension while I receive the extra benefit of pulling it's weight.

I have been very grateful for the suspension on a few hiking trips when taking them down a rock garden.  However, the vast majority of the time, cycling, I'd prefer to not be towing the extra weight.

Comment: Do you have a feeling for the extra weight of the suspension on top of that of the trailer+kids?

Comment: Very little.  Suspension, maybe five pounds.  Trailer: 35lbs, Kids: 55lbs.  It would probably only be noticeable when I was commuting with the trailer and no kids.

Comment: @SuspendedUser does the suspension cause jerking on the tongue like the spring hitches do?  I always found that to be the source of my energy drains.  I changed the hitch and no problems sense.

Comment: Not that I notice.  I feel jerkiness from the hitch on uphill/downhill transitions, but not over bumps.  I believe that's just the design of the slip hitch however.